# Eclipse CDT: Unresolved inclusion of stl header

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++builder, header-files, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse to edit sources, compiled under C++ Builder, but stuck with `Unresolved inclusion` problem.

For example, code like:

```
#include <vector>
```

Gives `Unresolved inclusion: <vector>` error in Eclipse IDE. C++ Builder indeed has no `vector` file, instead it has `vector.h` which is used by compiler.

Eclipse IDE gives no error if I write

```
#include <vector.h>
```

How do I tell Eclipse to use `vector.h` when it sees `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Which release of C++ Builder do you have, model 1997 or 2010 or inbetween?

Comment: According to this page [wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder#Version_history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder#Version_history) version 4 was released in 1999! That might be a big part of your problem. You can easily get free, and very much newer, versions of g++ or Microsoft Visual C++ Express.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["string could not resolved" error in Eclipse for C++ (Eclipse can't resolve standard library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c-eclipse-cant-resolve-stan)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This allowed me to avoid Eclipse "Unresolved inclusion" error.

In my case I had to find the location of the C++ vector header on my computer (which is a Mac):

```
find /usr/local -name vector -print
```

I found the correct include location in folder "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1".  Then I set my project eclipse settings like so:

```
Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->GNU C++->(Add)->"/usr/include/c++/4.2.1"
```

I'm not using C++ Builder, but my solution might address part of your trouble.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try use "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings". Go to the project properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Path > Providers tab
then check "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" if it is not.

None of the other solutions (play with include path, etc) worked for me for the type 'string', but this one fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, with Eclipse CDT Oxygen, none of the solutions described here worked for me (including the "Provider" - "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings").
What works for me is:

- Install Cygwin, with notably the following packages (maybe not all are strictly needed for this):

  - libgcc1
  - cygwin32-gcc-core, cygwin32-gcc-g++
  - gcc-g++
  - mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core, mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++
- In Project Properties:

  - Go to "C/C++ Build" - "Tool Chain Editor" and select "Cygwin GCC" as the "Current toolchain":
    [image: Project Properties - Tool Chain Editor]
  - Go to "C/C++ General" - "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macors etc.", in the "Providers" tab, select:

    - "CDT Users Setting Entries" (I need them for other includes, such as the Google Test ones, which I manually referenced);
    - "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cygwin".
      [image: Project Properties -Providers]

Answer (score 2):

memory and memory.h don't refer to the same source.

One is for c, the other for c++

Do you have the right includes source in your project settings ?

Comment: OK, there is conditional `#if !defined(__USING_STD_NAMES__)` which is obviously true when included as <memory.h> and false if included as <memory>. How do I tell all this stuff to Eclipse?

Comment: To better understand your need let me ask : why do you need to tell that to eclipse ? If you really need memory.h then use the #include <memory.h> but if you want to use the c++ header <memory> then make sure that the path to the C++ bluider includes file are set in the Properties(of your project)>C/c++ general > path and symbols>include > your compiler Then you can add the correct ressources

Comment: changed `memory` to `vector` to show my point. There is no vector.h in gnu c++, but C++Builder has this file and uses it when it sees `#include <vector>`

Comment: hm... if you go F3 on  #include <vector.h> the file is itself including #include <vector> ? At least that is what is done with my gcc headers. If your C++ builder includes are in the include path of your project then it should resolve the name and find it.