# "string could not resolved" error in Eclipse for C++ (Eclipse can't resolve standard library)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have the following code in eclipse for c++ and it's underlining `string` and `cout` and saying could not be resolved.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string s;
    s = "hello world";
    cout << s;
    return 0;

}
```

Anyone know why?

edit: screenshot

**Edit:** I have found a solution thanks everyone (see answers).

[image]

Comment: But it compiles and works OK, right?  I have had this issue myself and I think it's related to eclipse being unable to find the include directory for the toolchain you are using.  Check the settings.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977542/eclipse-cdt-unresolved-inclusion-of-stl-header

Comment: Check this out, I think the answer is not that complicated : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433448/eclipse-cdt-symbol-null-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: another possible reason: I forgot install g++. For example in Fedora25, `dnf install gcc-c++-6.3.1-1.fc25.x86_64  libstdc++-devel-6.3.1-1.fc25.x86_64`. Then rebuild index.

Comment: After following C++ tutorial on youtube, I found you needed the following code:      "using namespace std; "    , clean project , then recompile and run.

Comment: Fixed by a combination of things my end - (1) convert to C++ project, (2) selecting toolchain (3) stl-unresolved paths fix (follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663879/4361073)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>" in a C++ file in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/how-to-solve-unresolved-inclusion-iostream-in-a-c-file-in-eclipse-cdt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to have both [minGW and MSY](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW)S installed and added to PATH.

The problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 75):

I've also had this issue.

I've found out that it is because Eclipse couldn't find all include headers.

#### Easy fix:

This simple and quick solution might fix your problem (for example, when the Eclipse project was moved to a different location on disk, then imported again in Eclipse), if not, jump to the next section (*Detailed fix*).

1. Go to project > properties > **C/C++ Build** > **Tool Chain Editor**
2. Change the **Current toolchain** to any other value, click **Apply**
3. Set the **Current toolchain** to the original value, click **Apply**
4. Compile your project

#### Detailed fix:

Before proceeding check if your toolchain is properly installed.

1. Switch to a new workspace.
2. Remove .cproject file and the ".settings" folder
3. Import your project as Makefile project (or just create a new if you prefer CDT Build system)
4. Go to project-> properties->C/C++ Build->Toolchain editor. Choose your toolchain.
5. Press project->Index->Rebuild
6. If the problem isn't resolved, change system language to English and try the above steps again.

#### Outdated answer:

*This answer has been outdated. Proceed if nothing of the above helps*

If the previous steps don't help we'll need to setup include directories manually (not recommended though)

1. Search all unresolved headers using "Right click on Project > Index > Search for unresolved includes".
2. Search their locations using "find /usr/include/ -name vector -print"
3. Put include folder paths to "Right click on Project > Properties > C++ General/Path and Symbols/C++"
4. Run "Right click on Project > Index > Rebuild"
5. Start from step 1 if there are any unresolved symbols left.

Comment: Eclipse can't resolve standard library: Thank you very much - just what I was looking for. Seems like there ought to be a more automated way of doing this. I ended up all the way down in 
/usr/include/c++/4.7.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h before Eclipse stopped complaining. Home some of these key words index well on google.

Answer (score 6):

I've just replied to the related question given by Vanuan ([Eclipse CDT: Unresolved inclusion of stl header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977542/eclipse-cdt-unresolved-inclusion-of-stl-header)), and this is my answer :

You could also try use "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings". Go to the project properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Include Path > Providers tab
then check "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" if it is not.

None of the other solutions (play with include path, etc) worked for me for the type 'string', but this one fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure your environment is properly setup in Eclipse so it knows the paths to your includes. Otherwise, it underlines them as not found.

Comment: added screenshot. im new to this

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Adding include path does work for all except std::string.

I noticed in the mingw-Toolchain many system header files *.tcc

I added filetype *.tcc as "C++ Header File" in Preferences > C/C++/ File Types.
Now std::string can be resolved from the internal index and Code Analyzer.
Perhaps this is added to Eclipse CDT by default in feature.

I hope this helps to someone...

PS: I'm using Eclipse Mars, mingw gcc 4.8.1, Own Makefile, no Eclipse Makefilebuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Change the CurrentBuilder in Properties/C/C++ Build/ToolChainEditor to another value and apply it. Then again change it the original value. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with AOSP (clang).

Add `external\libcxx\include` to includes and `_LIBCPP_COMPILER_CLANG` to symbols

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is a simple solution,

Just go to File -> Convert to a C/C++ Autotools Project
Select your project files appropriately.

Inclusions will be added to your project file

Answer (score 0):

**Set `${COMMAND}` to `g++` on Linux**

Under "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc." and "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" there is an undefined `${COMMAND}` variable if you imported the sources from an existing Makefile project.

Eclipse tries to run that command to parse its stdout to find headers, but `${COMMAND}` is not set by default, and so it is not able to do so.

I have explained this in more detail at: [How to solve "Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>" in a C++ file in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/how-to-solve-unresolved-inclusion-iostream-in-a-c-file-in-eclipse-cdt/51099533#51099533)