# C++ converting an int to a string

Tags: string, int

I know this is extremely basic but I'm very new to C++ and can't seem to find an answer.  I'm simply trying to convert a few integers to strings.  This method works:

```
int a = 10;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string str = ss.str();
```

but when I need to convert the second and third ones like this:

```
int b = 13;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string str2 = ss.str();

int c = 15;
stringstream ss;
ss << b;
string str3 = ss.str();
```

I get this error:

```
'std::stringstream ss' previously declared here
```

Do I need to somehow close stringstream?  I've noticed that if I put them far away from each other in my code the compiler doesn't mind but that doesn't seem like something I should do.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: are you using stringstream just to convert the int to a string? you should trying using std::to_string instead.

Comment: yes.  I've tried to_string and my compiler doesn't understand it.  I get this error: Function 'to_string' could not be 
 resolved.  I made sure that i was also using #include <iostream> and
#include <string>

Comment: add the string header to your code. see my example below

Comment: try std::to_string(int), It will work fine.

Comment: to_string is a property of newer C++ versions. Many compilers won't understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: For conversion like these, I have a bookmark https://www.converttypes.com/

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to redeclare the same stringstream with the same name. You can modify your code like this in order to work :

```
 int b = 13;
stringstream ss2;
ss2 << a;
string str2 = ss2.str();
```

Or like this if you don't want to redeclare it :

```
int b = 13;
ss.str(""); // empty the stringstream
ss.clear();
ss << a;
string str2 = ss.str();
```

You can also use , which is much quicker :

```
int c = 42;
std::string s = std::to_string(c);
```

Comment: @JavaRunner, is there any other reason not to use `std::to_string`? As I now consider replacing `stringstreams` used for one value with `to_string`, but not sure, this is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The `stringstream` is a variable just like any other. To make the idiom work twice without change, put it in braces:

```
int a = 13;
string str2;
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    str2 = ss.str();
} // ss ceases to exist at the closing brace

int b = 15;
string str3;
{
    stringstream ss; // now we can make a new ss
    ss << b;
    str3 = ss.str();
}
```

Since C++11, you can do

```
std::string str4 = std::to_string( b );
```

or (with `c` of arbitrary type)

```
std::string str5 = ( std::stringstream() << c ).str();
```

There are other solutions, of course.

Comment: thank you for the info.  when I did it that way I got no errors however when I tried to use the strings outside of the brackets later in my code it said they weren't defined in this scope.  I think I solved my problem though, I'm just going to use different names for each stringstream.

Comment: @user2162870 Note how I declared the strings here, outside the braces. Also, you might consider factoring it into a function. (You might even call the function `to_string` to simplify the eventual migration to C++11.) Copy-paste code is harder to maintain.

Comment: How does the `( std::stringstream() << b ).str()` idiom work? As far as I can see, `<<` returns an `ostream&`, which doesn't have `str()`.

Comment: @TrygveFlathen Before C++11, `std::stringstream() << b` would take the stream as an `std::ostream &` lvalue reference which did not accept a temporary. When rvalue references were added to the language, a generic overload was added to the library, so I should update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#include <string>

int a = 10;
std::string s = std::to_string(a);
```

Comment: I've tried to_string and my compiler doesn't understand it. I get this error: Function 'to_string' could not be resolved. I made sure that i was also using #include <iostream> and #include <string>

Comment: what's your development environment?

Comment: I do have the #include <string> statement.  I'm using eclipse on macOS.

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c ...but it sounds like your path may be setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The particular error you are getting is telling you that you can't declare two variables with the same name (`ss` in your case) within the same scope.

If you wanted to create a new `stringstream` you could call it something else.

But there are other ways to convert an int to a string.. you could use [std::to_string()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare:

```
using namespace std;
```

Then insert the code:

```
int a = 10;
ostringstream ssa;
ssa << a;
string str = ssa.str();

int b = 13;
ostringstream ssb;
ssb << b;
string str2 = ssb.str();

int c = 15;
ostringstream ssc;
ssc << c;
string str3 = ssc.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way i can think of doing it is:

```
string str = string(itoa(num));
```