# "string" type could not be resolved Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to do this:

```
#include <string>

class Medicine{

    string name;


};
```

but it's not working at all. I tried Right Click on the Project -> Index -> Searched for Unresolved Includes and it says: Unresolved includes in the Project(0 matches). It's not working with std::string either. What should I do?

Comment: @David it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

You should either fully qualify `string` with the namespace it belongs to (`std`):

```
#include <string>

class Medicine {
    std::string name;
//  ^^^^^
};
```

Or use a `using` declaration:

```
#include <string>

using std::string; // <== This will allow you to use "string" as an
                   //     unqualified name (resolving to "std::string")

class Medicine {
    string name;
//  ^^^^^^
//  No need to fully qualify the name thanks to the using declaration
};
```

Comment: The std::string name it's not working. Neither is the second one using std::string (eclipse says: syntax error).

Comment: @CucerzanRares: It compiles [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx$223). Please make sure you copy everything exactly.

Comment: @CucerzanRares: Could you provide any more info on what is not working? What message are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: @CucerzanRares, when you say "it's not working" and don't explain what the problem is, a programmer dies somewhere in the world. Please be careful.

Comment: @Jueecy Or a doctor dies.  Or a mechanic.  Depends on who you're talking to.

Comment: @Jueecy I already said the error: Type 'std::string' could not be resolved

Comment: @CucerzanRares: Does your program include only and exactly those 4 lines?

Comment: Is this just Eclipse's editor complaining? That is, does your code **compile**?

Comment: @AndyProwl the #include is in a medicine.h header file.

Comment: @Johnsyweb No, it doesn't compile

Comment: @CucerzanRares: Please try to compile that simple, 4 line program. With *nothing else inside*. If it doesn't compile, then there's probably something wrong with the project settings or some global Eclipse settings. If the simple minimal 4-line program compiles, then it means the problem is with additional stuff you have

Comment: @AndyProwl If i am in a .cpp file it recognises the string name but if I am in a header file i receive the error. :( I just don't get why it's working in .cpp and it doesn't in .h...

Comment: @CucerzanRares You seem to be dealing with a different problem than the one in your posted question then.

Comment: @DrewDormann All I know is that this eclipse is weird.

Comment: @cucerzan-rares How are you compiling a header file‽

Answer (score 1):

The `string` class (of the  header) is defined inside the std namespace. You are missing `using std::string;` or `std::` before `string` in the object declaration.

If you still can't fix it then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182742/493122).

Comment: none of those it's working

Comment: @CucerzanRares They do. You are missing something.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, it's not working for me. I am working in Eclipse for C++

Comment: @CucerzanRares, watch edit.

Answer (score 0):

try  creating a new console project and keeping it to this simple code below. If this doesn't work then possibly you're eclipse isn't setup for c++ correctly. The default download for an eclipse c++ environment is here http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

```
#include "stdafx.h"//optional depending if you have precompiled headers in VC++ project
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Medicine
{
    string name;        
};

// or use this alternative main if one below doesn't work
//int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Medicine test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's working. But when I am in a header file it doesn't recognise the string.

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work  if you've #included <string> and used  "using std::string;" in the header. I think you need to post more code so we can see more of what you're doing. Specifically post the code from the header file that eclipse is complaining about, exactly as it appears in your project.