# Android NDK inclusion errors with cURL

Tags: android, c++, curl, android-ndk

I'm working on an Android project, where we have made all the server calls in C++ code, because it is to work on both iOS and Android. The iOS app has cURL functioning in it's native enviorment, but our Android app can't even get the proper includes to work. It's both in our C++ file, where it can't resolve things like std::string, and in the cURL library, where it can't resolve size_t and so on.

I've looked at various other posts, and tried a bunch of things, the only thing to seems to help is importing different libraries from the NDK through path and symbols, but according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c), that is an outdated fix, and I still haven't gotten it to work, even with extensive imports.

The include that fails is , and then just a lot of member_declaration not found, and unresolved variable errors.

Also is jstring the equivalent to std::string, or is that completely wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Application.mk in your JNI folder add:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

This will add the STL library, with std::string, size_t and so on.