# Eclipse, C++ method str() could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

Using the default str() example from:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/

```
// stringstream::str
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream, std::stringbuf

int main () {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.str ("Example string");
  std::string s = ss.str();
  std::cout << s << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The code helper is saying `str()` could not be resolved, when building there is no errors related to `str()`

I have `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` on in Eclipse

And unchecked use global provider with the flags:

```
"${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"
```

I also tried changing toolchains back and forth but no luck.

Comment: Chack the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905025/string-could-not-resolved-error-in-eclipse-for-c-eclipse-cant-resolve-stan

Comment: I tried running the same code on visual studio 2013 and it's working fine.

Comment: @AhsanMustafa It looks more like an Eclipse IDE error than a syntax or code error

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer got it :D

Comment: I have actually checked that out first, but I tried those options so far but no luck, I can actually run the program too.

Comment: How long have you used the IDE?

Comment: Try this link then: https://codeyarns.com/2014/11/07/could-not-be-resolved-error-in-eclipse-cdt/

Comment: To solve it, I created a new project in the same workspace copied the files and it compiled fine... Seems like an issue with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somehow caused by the structure of the g++ header files. In header `<sstream>` there are only the 'basic' template classes defined. I had the same error with a `ostringstream` when calling the `str()` method.
When I changed the variable type in my code to `std::basic_ostringstream<char>`, the error went away. Also autocompletion worked again (it didn't work before, which is a good sign that the eclipse scanner is somehow having problems). Of course  this is not a real good solution, because it uses the basic_* type, but it is one to get rid of the (harmless) error. The typedefs for the 'official' types like `ostringstream` are forward-declared in the header `<iosfwd>`. 
When I include a typedef (in the global namespace) in my code after the standard include files:

```
typedef std::basic_ostringstream<char> ostringstream;
```

and use this type `ostringstream` instead of `std::ostringstream`, the error also goes away. So the problem is caused by the forward declarations in the standard header file `<iosfwd>` (which does not mean that these headers a wrong, simply the eclipse scanner is puzzeled by this).

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609 btw.