# How to solve "Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>" in a C++ file in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, iostream

I download [eclipse for c++](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) (cdt-master-8.0.2.zip).

When I write:

```
#include <iostream>
```

It marks:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 101):

1. Click **Project → Properties**.
2. Expand **C/C++ General**.
3. Click **Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.**
4. Click the **Providers** tab.
5. Check **CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings**.
6. Check **Use global provider shared between projects**.
   [image: Preprocessor Properties]
7. Click **Apply and Close**.

Comment: I got a Unsolved inclusion from #include <string>. But it worked to me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me.  I still got flaky behaviour similar to Natanael until I deleted the project, re-imported, cleand and re-built.

Comment: I then also needed to set "Command to get compiler specs" in Eclipse Photon under Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099533/895245

Comment: For me it was `CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Settings Cross ARM` but the bloody eclipse always used gcc instead of my arm-none-eabi-gcc. After two hours realized I had to uncheck and recheck the setting to force eclipse to rerun the scanner.

Answer (score 18):

I use Eclipse for cross compiling and I have to add the explicit directories for some of the standard C++  libraries. Right click your project and select Properties. You'll get the dialog shown in the image. Follow the image and use the + icon to explicitly add the paths to your C++ libraries. [image]

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that your file has .cpp extension and not .c, I just had this problem

Answer (score 6):

I tried all previously mentioned answers, but in my case I had to manually specify the include path of the iostream file. As I use MinGW the path was:

C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++

You can add the path in Eclipse under:
Project > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes > Add. I hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

Install gcc.

If you're on linux, use the package manager.

If you're on Windows, use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: Installing gcc is not always sufficient to resolve the inclusion.

Comment: Solves the problem 99% of the time. Why else would iostream not load, unless there's something terribly wrong with your system? I think that we could say this sort of response for every answer, e.g. if its a syntax error and someone fixes it, the response could be, "it could be the compiler that has a bug". But, the chances of that happening are pretty low.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya: I think he means installing gcc is only one of several required steps. (Unless eclipse can magically detect that gcc was suddenly installed?  It might, I don't know)

Comment: Note that I used eclipse for a month working on a project, and suddenly all my #include statements got this warning (gcc obviously installed), so installing gcc is not a real solution.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was not the *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings*. Only after I included *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cygwin* did the parser recognized my `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't used this IDE before.  Read Eclipse's "Before You Begin" page and follow the instructions to the T.  This will make sure that Eclipse, which is only an IDE, is actually linked to a compiler.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse with Cygwin and this worked for me:

Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Includes... > Providers 
and select "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cygwin [Shared]".

Answer (score 1):

For those using a fresh install of Ubuntu, or another Linux distro,
make sure your have at least the package "build-essential" before you try to compile Eclipse CDT projects.

At Terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It should be enough to compile and run your apps.

Of course, you can also perform full g++ install,  using:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 1):

I am running eclipse with cygwin in Windows.

Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Includes... > Providers 
and selecting "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler settings Cygwin" in providers list solved problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Also set `${COMMAND}` to `g++` on Linux**

Under:

- Project
- Properties
- C/C++ General
- Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.
- Providers
- CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
- Command to get compiler specs

Replace:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

If you don't do this, the Eclipse stdout shows:

```
Unable to find full path for "-E"
```

and logs under `${HOME}/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log` show:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2020-04-23 20:17:07.288
!MESSAGE Error: Cannot run program "-E": Unknown reason
```

because `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS}` are empty, and so Eclipse tries to execute the `-E` that comes next.

I wonder if we can properly define the `COMMAND` and `FLAGS` variables on the settings, but I tried to add them as build variables and it didn't work.

C version of the question: ["Unresolved inclusion" error with Eclipse CDT for C standard library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-error-with-eclipse-cdt-for-c-standard-library-headers)

Tested on Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0), Ubuntu 19.10, and this [minimal Makefile project with existing sources](https://github.com/cirosantilli/hello-cpp/tree/0fbc72291034456435dff1c3523cf0a69dba5a70).

Comment: That's what worked for me. Needed to substitute COMMAND for g++, and of course rebuild the index again.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, with Eclipse CDT Oxygen, none of the solutions described here worked for me. I described what works for me in this other question: [Eclipse CDT: Unresolved inclusion of stl header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988315/1180868).

Answer (score 0):

I'd had this issue with Eclipse 2019-12 where the includes were previously being resolved, but then weren't.  This was with a Meson build C/C++ project.  I'm not sure exactly what happened, but closing the project and reopening it resolved the issue for me.