# Unresolved inclusion: iostream C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I installed C++ eclipse Ide in Linux but when I create a project, I got error "Unresolved inclusion: iostream" error.

I checked all other questions related to this, but nothing helped :(

Please any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with the shell and see if it'll compile with the same error. I suspect a path/settings is missing in eclipse to the libraries.

Comment: What g++ packages have you installed?

Comment: How can I install g++?

Comment: I checked gcc, and I get "gcc is already the newest version."

Comment: Have you tried going to the GNU website and downloading or reading the installation instructions?