# Unresolved inclusion

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse in Ubuntu. I'm trying to run hello world program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Programm runs fine, but in IDE I have errors:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved
```

I suppose something wrong with inclusion, but what?

Comment: Already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream)

Comment: This is mostly for Windows install and I need Linux configuration

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed gcc?

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-<version>
```

By the way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream) should be the answer to your problem.

**edit**

If you have already installed gcc, maybe you have to specify the filesystem path where *iostream.h* is located. You have to add include path in eclipse settings, take a look [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm).

- Alt+Enter to open projects proprerties.
- Expand C/C++ General and select Paths and Symbols.
- Click Add to define new element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
- Click Edit to change selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
- Click Delete to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
- Click Export to make selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) exported.
- Click Unexport to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) from export list.
- Click Move up and Move down to set elements (Include Paths, Library paths etc) order.

[image: Include]

Comment: Yes, I have installed gcc. gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)