# An error in #include <iostream> as "unresolved inclusion"

Tags: eclipse

I am new with eclipse and know not much about that. I just installed it from the website and is using it for basic programs. Please suggest me a basic solution for this.

Comment: Did you see this other question that looks identical to yours? (If it isn't you should provide more information) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream)