# Unresolved Inclusions using C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm in the proces of implementing an Object-Recognition system using OpenCV, however I am having problem with the headers, it keeps saying unresolved, and the functions of the libraries are still red. I am ending up with lots of unresolved inclusions in the open-source opencv - Why am I getting those?

And the version I'm using is: opencv_java451.

I've made a search of the unresolved inclusions.
Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

Also I am getting an red error on interface.h located in opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/hal.

Also it's like I don't have a proper compiler for C++?
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/how-to-solve-unresolved-inclusion-iostream-in-a-c-file-in-eclipse-cdt

Comment: I've tried that one, also lots of others, but it didn't fix my problem. It's like the problem is with the compiler settings.
EDIT: I've updated my thread.