# Eclipse Juno Indexer Broken - Can't find any STL headers

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, indexing

Ever since updating to Juno the indexer in Eclipse seems toast.

First the following is deprecated so I disabled it:

```
 C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Automate discovery of paths and symbols: Unchecked
```

Next, make sure this is enabled:

```
 C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, Etc -> Enable language settings providers for this project
```

Then under the Providers tab I check everything.

Do a index rebuild, build entire project.

Every single STL reference is missing.  std::string, std::vector for example report as unresolved externals.  Yes everything compiles fine and runs.  It is just very annoying to see 10,000 errors in Eclipse.   In terms of Android development Eclipse actually thinks they are real errors and prevents deployment to the device.

I am running Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

If I go Right Click Project -> Index -> Search for unresolved includes I get a big list of files all claiming "unresolved inclusion: bits/c++config.h"

So I `locate c++config.h` and add the path to eclipse includes, rebuild index, no change.

I'm totally pulling hairs on this.  Eclipse has never made me so frustrated!

Comment: I burned a whole dev day attempting this the other day.  Still not solution.  Ubuntu x64 Eclipse Juno  refuses to find all the stl headers when indexing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977542/eclipse-cdt-unresolved-inclusion-of-stl-header
Refer this link. Helpful

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution? Use Indigo.
The first time I downloaded Juno, it seemed to work great. I tried to add a plugin (Java Script editor) and it died. After un/re-installing it worked but could not locate stl (>7000 problems) and was so slow it was not useable for those two reasons. Down loaded Indigo and back in business. sytem: Linux, 64, 6cpu, 8GB mem.