# Error check in Eclipse CDT using Makefiles

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, llvm, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse to develop my project, which bases on my custom makefile system. I have to use custom Makefile project because I want to tevelop LLVM porject pased on the LLVM makefile system, see: http://llvm.org/docs/Projects.html.

I created an "empty makefile" project in eclipse, I'v chosen the build location (Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Build Location) and added every needed library sources (Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and sources).

The project build and executes like it should. The problem is that a lot of lines is underscored with red colour as errors. This is obvious because eclipse chcecks for erros executing gcc and it does not executes it unless I'm using Makefiles (or maybe I am wrong ...).

Anyway - is there any way to check for syntax (and other types of) errors while using eclipse with makefiles?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you add a reproducible minimum working example? An LLVM build of a single “Hello World” C file, with the Makefile, the Eclipse version number, and the exact steps you follow to create the Eclipse project?

Comment: It is not so easy to get the "hello world" example based on LLVM project template running - you have to download LLVM sources and compile them, because to build custom project you nedd LLVM sources and objects (compiled libraries) as makefile dependencies. Anyway it is straightforward process, please download sources and compile them following instruction: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started and then in $LLVMSRC/projects there is "sample" directory containing all makefiles needed. Then you have to: cd sample; mkdir build; cd build; ../configure; make;

Comment: You should have this example up and running (the source of hello world is placed in sample/tools/sample/main.c). If you want to have more complicated example, rename the main.c file to main.cpp, replace its content with code found on the end of this site: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html and add following line to the beginning of sample/tools/sample/Makefile: "LINK_COMPONENTS = all" (without quotes) - this is really easy to do, and I'm afraid there is no easier way to give you runnable example :( After importing this project to eclipse, I've got tons of errors.

Comment: The eclipse version is 4.2.1 and the steps to create eclipse project are: 1) file->new C++ Project->MakeFile Project (Empty Project) -> point to the sources -> finish; Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Build location change to "${workspace_loc:/sample/build}"; Project->Properties->C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Gnu C++ -> append "home/<username>/llvm/src/include" and "/usr/include/c++/4.7.2". After these steps I have no errors shown with includes but a lot like "Type 'std::string' could not be resolved" or "Symbol 'stderr' could not be resolved"

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977542/eclipse-cdt-unresolved-inclusion-of-stl-header), or google "eclipse unresolved symbols". You need to add the paths of your includes to your project settings, so Eclipse editor/indexer can find them.

The question in the link is for unresolved includes, but it also applies to all unresolved symbols.

Comment: by the way, those errors are totally unrelated to makefile. It's just that the indexer of Eclipse cannot find them.

Comment: Please look at my comments - I have of course added all paths to includes in project settings. It discovers all includes (I can even ctrl+click on them) BUT the errors still remain.

Comment: yes, I read them, but apparently there is still something missing. also try to add `/usr/include/` and `/usr/include/c++/4.7.2/backward` to the include paths.

Comment: This helped. I had a very similar problem: llvm project, red underlining in eclipse. I went to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> [the "includes" tab] -> Gnu C++ -> and added there /usr/local/include folder, which is where my llvm folder with includes is located.