# How to add includes to an autotools project

Tags: c, eclipse, autotools

I'm trying use autotools in Eclipse. Everything works fine except "Unresolved inclusion: " and all next inclusions. Compilation is fine, but editor doesn't know standard libraries. I try to find some linker settings... Where can I find some settings for that?

Thanks

Comment: Project -> Properties -> C\C++ Build -> Settings

Comment: I have only 2 tabs here (Binary parsers, error parsers). It is different from a project without autotools.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/q/5977542 looks similar.